# Value of field "Persons" is not being displayed in Workflow

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a list called "Hotel Booking". It contain a field called "Persons" whose type is Person/Group.

I have made a copy of SharePoint default approval workflow and making changes in it so this field "Persons" is sent by workflow when email is sent.

Problem is it is not showing this field in email and it comes as blank. Please check following screenshots about how am I doing it.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

I think images are not visible so I am pasting links below.

> http://s32.postimg.org/kdyx2gu39/hb1.jpg
>   http://s32.postimg.org/e05p4ugr9/hb2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Is it a list workflow? If it is, you should be able to just use the current item and choose to return the value from the person field as email,display name or login.

[image]